# Why would CFAbort not work?

Tags: coldfusion

I am having an odd problem. There is a large request I am debugging so I threw a cfabort in at a particular spot before some processing is to occur. It doesn't appear to be working as the request keeps running in browser and shows up in the CF monitor, where I kill it manually. Throwing an error immediately works, though doing a cfabort with "showerror" doesn't. Any thoughts on what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found the culprit. I had debugging on and set to send output to ColdFire. I guess there was a massive amount of data related to the queries and that was still being created when I called cfabort, but ignored when throwing an error. I know I've run into this before so I guess now I have a place to find the answer again :-)